# Collapsible layout with custom view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

Hello i am using collapsible layout and I want the behaviour of layout to change according to my scroll event as shown in the image:

> 1. This is the by default image with list view and when user scrolls, the top layout should change and look like the one in second image.

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

How should I achieve this kind of behaviour using collapsible layout.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            <ImageView></ImageView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

Answer (score 0):

you just add TabLayout under the toolbar like below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayoutactivity_mainId"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: i dont want tab layout . Tab layout is going to remain the same but toolbar is getting replaced see the second image.

Comment: i cant understand what you saying.., am using the above layout for one of my appliction development

Answer (score 0):

Try to override this acording to your need. You can set layouts making visible/hide components in **CollapsableToolbar**.

```
 appbar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    header = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
                private State state;

                @Override
                public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                    if (verticalOffset == 0) {
                        if (state != State.EXPANDED) {
                            collapsingToolbar.setTitleEnabled(false);
                           // do something here
                        }
                        state = State.EXPANDED;
                    } else if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
                        if (state != State.COLLAPSED) {
                            collapsingToolbar.setTitle("All Jobs ");
                            collapsingToolbar.setTitleEnabled(true);

    //                  do something here      header.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.actionbar_gradient));
    //                        collapsingToolbar.setContentScrim(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.actionbar_gradient));
                            collapsingToolbar.setContentScrim(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.actionbar_bg));

    //                        collapsingToolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.actionbar_bg));

                        }
                        state = State.COLLAPSED;
                    } else {
                        if (state == State.IDLE) {
                            collapsingToolbar.setTitleEnabled(false);
                            container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        state = State.IDLE;
                    }
                }
            });
```

It worked for me try it....